# Reading input text parameter in Servlet from JSP for fileupload multipart

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, multipartform-data

I am creating a JSP page to upload a CSV or TXT file. The file data are separated by some delimiter. That I am retrieving from user using a Checkbox and based on the checked checkbox I am setting a text field value to respected checkbox value. I am also adding a checkbox for custom delimiter. When the user selects that checkbox the same textfield(where I am setting the value of other checkbox) is displayed and user is allowed to enter their custom delimiter.

I am also setting some other input hidden fields to pass String values and a Java object from previous servlet to next servlet.

As the JSP is for file uploading I cannot use `request.getParameter()`.
But I am able to read the text fields. I mean when user checks the delimiter checkbox other than the custom one, servlet is reading the text input. 
But when user checks custom checkbox and enters the cutom delimiter value, then its not able to read the text inpt properly.

Here is my JSP  `(FileUpload.jsp)` code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="fileupload"
            action="GenericFileUpload" onsubmit="return validateFile(this)"
            enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Please choose delimiter:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="," value="," />&nbsp;Comma(,)</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" id="|" value="|" />&nbsp;Pipe
                            Delimiter(|)</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="delimeter" id="custom" />&nbsp;Custom(Specify)</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="specify" class="control-group" style="display: none;">
                <label class="control-label" for="delimiter">Please provide
                    the delimiter:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input id="customdelimiter" type="text" name="delimiter"
                        placeholder="Specify Delimiter" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="transportTab"
                value="<c:if test="${transportTab != null}">${transportTab}</c:if>">

            <input type="hidden" name="scheduleData" value="${scheduleData}">

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="file">Please upload a
                    file:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="file" name="file" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

And Here is my JQuery for Checkbox(I know better way is to use radio nuttons. But I am using this)

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', true);
                    $(this).attr('disabled', false);
                    var delValue = $(this).val();
                    $('#customdelimiter').attr('value', delValue);

                } else {
                    $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', false);
                    $('#customdelimiter').attr('value', '');
                }
            });
            $('#custom').change(function() {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('#customdelimiter').attr('value', '');
                    $('#specify').slideDown("slow");
                } else {
                    $('#specify').slideUp("slow");
                    $('#customdelimiter').attr('value', '');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Based on the selected checkbox value I am setting the value of textbox to that value.

And part of my servlet (`FileUploadServlet.java`) to read the input values is,

```
FileItem fileItem=null;

        if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) 
        {
            try
            {
             List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
             String itemList[]=new String[items.size()];
             for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++)
             {
                 itemList[i]=new String();
             }
             int i=0;
             for (FileItem item : items) {

                    if (item.isFormField()) {
                        // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
                       itemList[i]=item.getString();
                       i++;

                    } else {

                        String delimiter=itemList[0];
                     System.out.println("delimiter value is "+delimiter);

                      String transportTab=itemList[1];
                   System.out.println("dataload value is "+transportTab);
                    String  scheduleDataString= itemList[3];
```

If I selet custom, and enters some value(say `:`),
string delimiter bcomes on,
transportTab becomes `:`
Means array index changes when adding custom.
Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: Array index changes where?

Comment: In the servlet. I mean 
`delimiter=itemList[0];
transportTab=itemList[1];` works when selecting appropriate checkbox(gets , or |)
But when selecting custom checkbox it gives
`on` value for delimiter and `:` (assuming I given : as custom delimiter) for transportTab string.

Comment: You have mentioned name="delimeter" for delimiter textbox, why don't you check the field name in your java code. Remove code where you are finding delimiter and transportTab by arrayindex.

Comment: Do you mean `request.getParameter("delimiter")`?

Comment: Obviously not. Wait for my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting value of fields using the array index is not a good idea. You can use `getFieldName()` to get the field name and extract the value.

getFieldName() will return you the element `name` attribute. For your case:

```
String delimiter =null, transportTab = null;
if("delimiter".equals(item.getFieldName()){
   delimiter = item.getString();
}
if("transportTab".equals(item.getFieldName()){
   transportTab = item.getString();
}
```

This way, you can get correct values for required attributes.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. U need to add one more paranthesis in the end of both `if`

Comment: @ShijuKBabu: I don't need to add paranthesis in the end of `if`, it is YOU who needs to do that :)

Comment: Yes. I know that. But in future some other may also look for same question and anser. So I said this only. Anyway thanks. it really helped me. I was stuck on this for the whole day.